# MongoDB is very slow on Azure Platform

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, mongodb-.net-driver

I was created MongoDB database in Linux Server (***Standard D2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory)***) on the Windows Azure Platform.
[image]

I'm testing data insert to database with following codes. But result is not good..! 47 second for inserting 100.000 record very bad. What is the problem?
[image]

Codes for insert to mongodb

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://root:bitnami@myserveraddress:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("testdb");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("foo");
var documents = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(i => new Item
{
    Address = "Address " + i,
    City = "City " + i,
    Index = i + 1,
    Name = "Name " + i,
    Status = i % 2 == 0,
    Surname = "Surname " + i,
    Title = "Title " + i,
    Town = "Town " + i
});
var models = documents.Select(s => new InsertOneModel<Item>(s)).ToList();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var result = collection.BulkWrite(models);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Seconds:" + sw.Elapsed.Seconds);
result.InsertedCount.Dump();
collection.Count(p => 1 == 1).Dump();
```

Comment: Very slow compared with what?

Comment: Sql Server bulk insert faster than MongoDB same data.

Comment: And how are you inserting data in Mongo? :D

Comment: Excuse me. What ?

Comment: Show us the code... who knows what approach you're using to insert that data in Mongo. Maybe this is the issue

Comment: I was added image. But I'm writing codes now..

Comment: I added codes..

Comment: Ok now let's see what others think about your approach... In my case, I can't analyze it now, but at least I've pointed you to the right direction to get a good answer ;)

Comment: Yes you are right.. Thank you for this :)

Comment: Did you try to divide data insertion in many bulks and do them using parallelization (i.e. for example a `Parallel.For`)?

Comment: You should try to attach SSD disk and setup mongo to store files on it. Standard storage that is default for your VM is very slow for database. Open your VM in portal, click "Attach New Disk", select Premium SSD.

Answer (score 0):

My data files on Azure (Linux Virtual Machine - Standard D2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory))

Comment: Try to use DS2 series which will have SSD disk for operating system or attach new SSD disk to existing machine and move date files to it.